# Null reference check in c++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

The following code checks for a null reference and creates an object using `new` if detected.

The code compiles and the object is created successfully (as anticipated), but the program terminates unexpectedly on the line `ref.set_dat(55)` in function `main()` (also shown in comments) which is an unexpected behavior.

I don't seem to understand why does the method call to `set_dat()` method fail when the object is created successfully using `new`?

```
class X {
        private:
            int *_dat,*__dat;
        public:
            X(); // constructor
            ~X(); // destructor
            int get_dat() const {
                return *(this->_dat);
            }
            int get__dat() const {
                return *(this->__dat);
            }
            void set_dat(int data) {
                *(this->_dat)=data;
            }
            void set__dat(int data) {
                *(this->__dat)=data;
            }
    };

    X::X() {
        this->_dat=new int(0); // assign default value of 0
        this->__dat=new int(0);
        cout << "Construction Successful\n";
    }

    X::~X() {
        delete this->_dat;
        delete this->__dat;
        _dat=NULL;
        __dat=NULL;
        cout << "Destruction Successful\n";
    }

    int main() {
        X *obj=NULL;
        X &ref=*obj;
        if (&ref==NULL) {
            cout << "NULL REFERENCE DETECTED\n";
            obj=new X;
        } else { // this must not execute
            cout << "YOU CANT BE HERE!!!\n";
        }
        ref.set_dat(55); // Program terminates at this statement
        cout << "Data 1 has value " << ref.get_dat() << endl;
        delete obj;
        cout << "Delete successful\n";
        obj=NULL;
        if (&ref==NULL) {
            cout << "NULL REFERENCE\nPROGRAM NOW TERMINATES";   
        } else { // this block must not execute
            ref.set_dat(58); 
            ref.set__dat(99);
            cout << "Data 1 now is " << ref.get_dat() << endl;
            cout << "Data 2 now is " << ref.get__dat() << endl;
            delete obj;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Please note that I have tried substituting `ref`, a reference, with `obj->`, the original object, but to no avail the same situation is encountered; the program terminates at the same line.

Can anyone please explain me why the program fails to execute at this particular line even after the creation of the object is successful and in the case of an incorrect syntax or logic, suggest me with the correct one? The expected pathway of the program is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: `X *obj=NULL; X &ref=*obj;` This is undefined behaviour, full stop. Even without compiler error, it's wrong, and can lead to pretty much anything. Thinking what it "should" do makes no sense.

Comment: @deviantfan I don't understand how is it an undefined behavior? Its fully logical. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Maybe it's logical for you, but the C++ standards don't allow this (period). If something is classified as "undefined behaviour" in the standard, it means that pretty much anything can happen. It can work, it can give an compiler error, it can crash, it can burn your computer... you get what I mean, it can do "anything". And it can change behaviour over time, etc.etc.etc.

Comment: In reality, this "anything " actually happens (well, usually it won't burn anything), because eg. the compiler relies on the code containing no UB, and may do something strange in your case.

Comment: @deviantfan Ok so considering that the c++ standards do not allow it, can you please give me a suggestion on how I can interpret the above logic in the correct standard form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: References in (valid) C++ code can *never* have the address NULL, or "point to nothing". So checking for null references is pointless in the first place. (Don't confuse references with "pointer without *")

Comment: references can't be null, so compiler can (and likely will, especially if it's clang) optimize your code with assumption that it's not null. So when you check it for null if, it can just assume it's never null, for example, end remove it. Also, names starting with `__` (double underscore) are reserved and shouldn't be used in any namespace.
Using `\n` in `cout` instead of `endl`, `NULL` instead of `nullptr`, using ptrs to store int, and raw ones at that... This whole code smell of bad practices =(

Comment: @DanM.: What is `newl`, and what is wrong with `'\n'`?

Comment: @DanM. About the "newl" / endl: It's actually not the same as a simple \n , it additionally flushes the stream.

Comment: @Dan M All right guys, I get that my code has bad practices but what I am trying to develop is a code which does not terminate or has mysterious bugs due to null references that occurs during runtime. I am trying to sort of the null references before hand and take required actions instead of letting the program crash or have unexpected outcomes hence to improve compatibility. If null references are not checked and handled beforehand, it can crash your program or generate anomalous outcomes; even you can't say no to that.

Comment: @deviantfan sorry, typo. Meant `endl`. I agree that `"\n"`is OK. But here it's used inconsistently and surely without the thought of flushing or not.

Comment: @zeus There are no null references in C++.

Comment: @zeus As melpomene said, and I said before too, `If null references are not checked and handled beforehand` is **wrong** because there are **no null references** in valid code. Sigh. `even you can't say no to that.` Yes I can. This is neither Java nor C#.

Comment: @zeus do you usually code in C++ or you came from other language with has nullreference exception or something?
In C++ references can't be null. You can force them to be, but it's UB. If in your program it's not uncommon to get null references, when it's doing something very wrong. Because why not use pointers then?

Comment: @melpomene In theory yes but in practice no as there can be situations/scenarios where a null object is referenced and which needs solving in order to prevent the program from crashing (in extreme cases)

Comment: @zeus ...you just don't want to hear it, right? If you have a null reference, and one that you can check with an `if` on top of that, your program is already broken. Yes, in practice. Crashing is actually the best outcome, not bad. Otherwise, there are funny things like variables which change their value without reason, etc.etc.etc. I repeat, this is not Java/C#. C++ actually bites back if you treat it badly.

Comment: @zeus in practice you should not use references to "reference" that object if it can be null. Use pointers. All the places there reference can become null should be eliminated and not some non-standards-compliant check added which may break any minute (as well as all other code using such references).

Comment: @zeus That happens when you dereference a null pointer, but that already has undefined behavior. You can't defend against that by checking afterwards; your program has already gone insane. You have to check the pointer before dereferencing.

Comment: @DanM. Missing "not"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has no interest in solving the errors of the code, and is asking for impossible things.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm sorry but I think you are kind of missing my point here; I get that null references are not present in c++ and is also not possible but there are scenarios where it can occur and cause a major hamper like crashing the whole program. What I am trying to do is to avoid such scenarios in programs which require real-time processing and cannot afford to crash. So what way/algorithm is there to prevent it other than to check if null reference is present or not?

Comment: All right guys, that was a hell of a debate!! But can anyone tell/suggest me the "actual" reason behind the line 'ref.set_dat(55);' not executing as required. In theory if possible ? Anyways thanks for your opinion pals.

Comment: `but there are scenarios where it can occur` Just no. The do "not" occur. You really need to understand what UB is. ... If your program is crashing, you need to fix the error where it is, not by introducing more errors. ... We told you the reason, in theory and practice: UB. It's a very real thing.

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks again mate. Please excuse my French but c++ can really be a bitch sometimes. Wonder if there will be some other language in near future which has all the functionalities of c++ and is far easier to code in.

Comment: @zeus Not in this elementary area. The problem is in your expectations.

Comment: @EJP Well expectations??? I just simply expect my code to run as reqired :-)

Comment: @zeus you should've asked why your program crashes or how to avoid UB with the example of your real code in which you get null ref or something and we'd help you.
Your program crashes obviously because `ref.set_dat(55)` here ref is still null. You set it here to null (invoking UB) `X &ref=*obj;`and never change it afterwards. But honestly, this is really bad code. If it's yours - then ask about how to make it better, If you can change it - do the same.

Comment: In addition `_dat` and `__dat` are poor naming (and the later is a reserved name). Is the next one be named `___dat` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> X *obj=NULL;
> X &ref=*obj;
> ```

A **reference** can never be NULL, only a **pointer** can be NULL.   But it is **undefined behavior** to dereference a NULL pointer.  This code is just plain wrong.

Your code re-assigns `obj` half-way, so the only way that `ref` can update automatically is if `ref` refers to the `obj` variable itself and not to the `X` object that `obj` points at:

```
int main() {
    X *obj = NULL;
    X* &ref = obj; // <-- a reference to a pointer
    if (ref == NULL) { // <-- OK
        cout << "NULL REFERENCE DETECTED\n";
        obj = new X; // <-- ref can now access the X
    } else { // this must not execute
        cout << "YOU CANT BE HERE!!!\n";
    }
    ref->set_dat(55); // <-- OK
    cout << "Data 1 has value " << ref->get_dat() << endl;
    delete obj;
    cout << "Delete successful\n";
    obj = NULL; // <-- ref no longer accesses an X
    if (ref == NULL) { // <-- OK
        cout << "NULL REFERENCE\nPROGRAM NOW TERMINATES";   
    } else { // this block must not execute
        ref->set_dat(58); 
        ref->set__dat(99);
        cout << "Data 1 now is " << ref->get_dat() << endl;
        cout << "Data 2 now is " << ref->get__dat() << endl;
        delete obj;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, change `ref` into a **pointer** instead of a **reference**:

```
int main() {
    X *obj = NULL;
    X** ref = &obj; // <-- a pointer to a pointer
    if (*ref == NULL) { // <-- OK
        cout << "NULL REFERENCE DETECTED\n";
        obj = new X; // <-- *ref can now access the X
    } else { // this must not execute
        cout << "YOU CANT BE HERE!!!\n";
    }
    (*ref)->set_dat(55); // <-- OK
    cout << "Data 1 has value " << (*ref)->get_dat() << endl;
    delete obj;
    cout << "Delete successful\n";
    obj = NULL; // <-- *ref no longer accesses an X
    if (*ref == NULL) { // <-- OK
        cout << "NULL REFERENCE\nPROGRAM NOW TERMINATES";   
    } else { // this block must not execute
        (*ref)->set_dat(58); 
        (*ref)->set__dat(99);
        cout << "Data 1 now is " << (*ref)->get_dat() << endl;
        cout << "Data 2 now is " << (*ref)->get__dat() << endl;
        delete obj;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer pal; It pretty much functions as I expected. So that means we must "never" reference a NULL initialized object right? Oh and does that mean my previous code failed to execute the line 'ref.set_data(55);' because ref was referring to the obj variable and not the memory location obj points to? Thanks again.

Comment: `So that means we must "never" reference a NULL initialized object right` Yes. `does that mean my previous code failed to execute ... because ... ` UB. Really. It doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: @zeus: There is no such thing as a "NULL initialized object".  A **pointer** to an object can be NULL, but the object itself cannot be NULL.  Your code failed because `*obj` invoked undefined behavior when `obj` was NULL, so `ref` was not referencing a valid `X` object, `&ref` could never be NULL so `new X` was not called, and `ref.set_dat()` crashed trying to access an invalid `X` object.

Comment: Thanks for everything guys :-)

Comment: Btw, clang has good warning system and can't prevent such things (also there are tools like UBSan designed specifically for catching UB).
For example, for you code it give this warning:
`42 : warning: reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false [-Wtautological-undefined-compare]
if (&ref==NULL) {
^~~ ~~~~`